# Create a connection point within a knex.js custom dialect

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I am creating a dialect within knex for a legacy database. I can create the sql and view the query with .toString(). Now how do I intercept the actual calls into the database? I would like to use node-adodb for the connection and I don't know how to tell knex to use it.

Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

From the knex [documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-node):

> You can even use knex without a connection, just for its query building features. Just pass in an empty object when initializing the library. Specify a client if you are interested in a particular flavour of SQL.

If I'm understanding your question properly, why not do just that, then make database calls through whatever connection library you please?